# XHR and jQuery.get() causing Chrome to crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have a process which polls a .csv file (stored on the server), then assigns values from the .csv file to divs on a webpage (IIS7.5 localhost for development).

I originally used an XMLHttpRequest process, but have now changed to a jQuery.get() process to retrieve the .csv data. Both processes cause the Google Chrome browser to crash (Aw, Snap!), typically after ~3000+ requests. As shown in the code below, I'm using a 100ms Interval to poll the .csv file (and the webpage's clock component). A 1000ms Interval will eventually be used, with the 100ms poll being used for testing purposes only.

I have tested this page on Firefox as well. The page didn't crash in the ~hour that I was running it, but the request frequency slowed dramatically, to the point that I believe the page would have crashed eventually.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window, document, undefined){
        window.onload = init;

            function init(){
                google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(myGet);
            }

            function get(URL) {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: URL,
                        dataType: 'text',
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                            var CallExternal = ExecuteExternal(data);
                            resolve(data.response);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            reject(Error(errorThrown));
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            function myGet() {
                get("Data.csv?" + new Date().getTime())
                    .then(function(result) {
                        //console.log("Success!");
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        setTimeout(myGet, 100);
                        Clock(); //Moved Clock() to here.
                    });
                //Clock(); Clock() used to be here.
            }
    })(window, document, undefined);
</script>
```

The ExecuteExternal() call is to an external JS file, which parses the .csv data and updates the webpage's divs.

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I've missed in the above code?

Edit: As recommended by Meiko, I've included a timer function to measure exactly how long the get() and external script process takes (i.e. one iteration). It appeared that the average time was just under 100ms, with some taking a little over 100ms. I've also moved the Clock() call into the final then() function, rather than having it outside the get() call.

Comment: too many requests ... I assume that the request is not ready after 100ms. And over the time you have to many of them in your queue.

Comment: This was one of my first assumptions, however Chrome's Dev Tools shows an average request time of less than 20ms.

Comment: maybe the processing of the data took longer?

Comment: Checking this now, I'll update the original post with my findings.

Comment: I've changed the Timeout poll to 1000ms, which is far greater than required, but Chrome still crashed. If the supplied code looks correct, what else could it be? Is my IIS maybe the issue?